# Non-conversation context in Google Home custom action

Tags: actions-on-google

I can ask follow up questions about a topic when using Google Home.  For example, "Ok Google, who was the 32nd president?" and then "Ok Google, when did he serve?".  I don't have to provide context or be in a 'conversation' (where Home is waiting for a response) to get the correct response.

So, how do I take advantage of that feature when writing a custom action?  I can have this type of dialog by using the conversation mode (setting expectUserResponse to true) but I don't want to require conversation mode.

Is that feature available to action developers or only available to built-in actions?

Comment: It isn't clear if your question is also meant to be more broad (how do you write a Direct Action, not just an Action). It also isn't clear which API you're planning to use (API.AI or the Action API directly) and what kind of dialog you're expecting to have with the user.

Comment: I'm using the Action API directly.  I know how to write a Direct Action and an Action.  Is one the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want basically is persistent data across conversations. You can store the cross conversation data in `conversationToken` field in the response, then the next time you receive the request, you can retrieve the data from `conversationToken`.

For your example, you can implement it as the following way: the custom action extracts the 'name' entity from the conversation and saves it in conversationToken. Then the next time when user refers to he or she, the action can use the value of the name entity to understand the context.

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data